# Stratified or unstratified binary data

Tags: logistic, dataset, binary-data, stratification

What is the difference between unstratified and stratidied binary data? How does the logistic model look like for each of them?

Answer (score 1):

Data stratification is dividing into mutually exclusive, collectively exhaustive subgroups. For binary data, the [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling#Example) covers why it can reduce error in estimating the outcome.

For the logistic model, you should apply [conditional logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_logistic_regression) for the stratified case.

Comment: Okay thanks! Which theory are statistical software (such as R and SAS) use when running logistic regression?

Comment: It looks like R has a builtin (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/clogit.html) for conditional logistic regression, you should start there.